# multiplication in finite fields irreducible polynomial

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

I just started doing some reading about multiplication in finite fields and i keep stumbling over one point:
in the field G(2^8)

how does 
x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 = 0
imply that
x^8 = x^4 + x^3 + x + 1
?

and, if addition is commutative, does this mean
x^4 = x^8 + x^3 + x + 1
too?

As i said i am absolutely new to this topic, and i am wondering if this is some kind of special rule for polynomials or if i miss something basic i should know :/

thanks in advance for help! (dummy explanation please^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a field of characteristic $2$, we have $1+1=0$, and therefore $a+a=0$ for all $a$.  So $-a=a$.  Nice, it is impossible to make a sign error.

Comment: Nicolas:  "impossible to make a sign error";  now *that* is nice! +1!